# Control de checkboxes activos (checked) con jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo varias opciones en un formulario de `checkbox`y un `<textarea>` Necesito que como mínimo uno de ellos no esté vacío, por ejemplo puede haber solo un `checkbox` `:checked` o ninguno **en el caso de que el** `textarea` no esté vacío. Lo que tengo es esto pero no funciona:

```js
$('#myBtn_denegar').click(function() {
  var checkerror = 5;
  if ($('#1').is(':checked')) {
    checkerror = checkerror - 1;
  }
  if ($('#2').is(':checked')) {
    checkerror = checkerror - 1;
  }
  if ($('#3').is(':checked')) {
    checkerror = checkerror - 1;
  }
  if ($('#4').is(':checked')) {
    checkerror = checkerror - 1;
  }
  if ($('#5').val(':checked')) {
    checkerror = checkerror - 1;
  }
  if (checkerror == 0) {
    $('#denegar_submit').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#denegar_submit').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <button id="myBtn myBtn_denegar" class='btn my-btn btn-primary btn-md my-btn'>lightbox</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form action="<?php echo $yomismo; ?>" method="post" class="center-element">
    <center>
      <h3>Seleccione uno o varios motivos</h3>
      <br>
      <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="denegar_ticket">
      <input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="<?php echo $ticket; ?>">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="checkBox hidden" name="1">
      <label for="1" class="checkBoxLabel">1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="checkBox hidden" name="2">
      <label for="2" class="checkBoxLabel">2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="3" class="checkBox hidden" name="3">
      <label for="3" class="checkBoxLabel">3</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="4" class="checkBox hidden" name="4">
      <label for="4" class="checkBoxLabel">4</label>
      <a href="#otro1" class="checkBoxLabel mya" data-toggle="collapse">OTRO</a>
      <br>
      <div id="otro1" class="collapse">
        <strong>Descripcción</strong>
        <textarea id="5" class="form-control" name="5"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </center>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  </form>
</div>
```

La idea es que cuando yo le haga click al boón en el que pone lightbox me vaya comprobando so yo selecciono alguna de las opciones o relleno el textarea...

También lo he probado de la siguiente forma:

```js
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(   
    function() {
        alert("El checkbox con valor " + $(this).val() + " está seleccionado");
    }
);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <button id="myBtn myBtn_denegar" class='btn my-btn btn-primary btn-md my-btn'>lightbox</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form action="<?php echo $yomismo; ?>" method="post" class="center-element">
    <center>
      <h3>Seleccione uno o varios motivos</h3>
      <br>
      <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="denegar_ticket">
      <input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="<?php echo $ticket; ?>">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="checkBox hidden" name="1">
      <label for="1" class="checkBoxLabel">1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="checkBox hidden" name="2">
      <label for="2" class="checkBoxLabel">2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="3" class="checkBox hidden" name="3">
      <label for="3" class="checkBoxLabel">3</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="4" class="checkBox hidden" name="4">
      <label for="4" class="checkBoxLabel">4</label>
      <a href="#otro1" class="checkBoxLabel mya" data-toggle="collapse">OTRO</a>
      <br>
      <div id="otro1" class="collapse">
        <strong>Descripcción</strong>
        <textarea id="5" class="form-control" name="5"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </center>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  </form>
</div>
```

Pero tampoco hace ningún resultado, lo normal es que por lo menos haga algo cuando se interactua con el checbox no?

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba utilizando un boolean i nota que estas asignando un valor al textarea al hacer

> $('#5').val(':checked')

a mi entender con esa condicion no estas comprobando nada, asi que la idea seria algo asi:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
 var checkerror = 0;
 if ($('#1').is(':checked')) {
  checkerror = 1;
  console.log($('#1'));
 }
 if ($('#2').is(':checked')) {
  checkerror = 1;
  console.log($('#2'));
 }
 if ($('#3').is(':checked')) {
  checkerror = 1;
  console.log($('#3'));
 }
 if ($('#4').is(':checked')) {
  checkerror = 1;
  console.log($('#4'));
 }
 if ($('#5').length>1) {
  checkerror = 1;
  console.log($('#5'));
 }

 if (checkerror == 0) {
  alert("Cancelado");
  e.preventDefault();
 } else {
  alert("Guarda");
 }
});
```

Con eso solo que te cumpla una de las condiciones te servira

**Edicion**
En un principio no lo habia entendido bien, para evitar el submit lo que deberias hacer es usar el evento "preventDefault()", con el prop lo que haces es desabilitar el boton, pero te envia el submit igualmente i te vuelve a recargar la pagina

Comment: Ahora no me da error pero tampoco hace lo que tiene que hacer... Es decir el botón está activo y se puede pulsar aunque no se cumplan las condiciones...

Comment: prueba con las condiciones al reves, es decir invertir los bloques del if(checkerror)

Comment: es decir primero el false y luego el true dentro del if? lo he probado y tampoco me funciona... Soy un manazas con esto del jquery xD

Comment: He editado la respuesta, prueba ahora a ver si funciona

Comment: Tampoco hace nada, ni se inmuta...

Comment: Te paso un jsFiddle donde funciona bien habiendo hecho algun pequeño cambio [https://jsfiddle.net/42yh1t4j/](https://jsfiddle.net/42yh1t4j/)